# Trigger using multiple table data

Tags: oracle, plsql, triggers

```
create or replace 
trigger audit_att_eval
    AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE OF evaluation ON attendance
    FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
  fname VARCHAR2(22);
  sname VARCHAR2(22);
  ctitle VARCHAR(30);
  ostartdate DATE;
  oinstructor VARCHAR2(12);
BEGIN
  SELECT student.first_name, student.surname, course.title, offering.start_date, offering.instructor
  INTO fname, sname, ctitle, ostartdate, oinstructor
  FROM student, course, offering, attendance
  WHERE student.student_id = attendance.student_id
  AND attendance.offering_id = offering.offering_id
  AND offering.course_id = course.course_id;
IF (:NEW.evaluation = 0)
    THEN
      INSERT INTO eval_audit
      VALUES (fname, sname, ctitle, ostartdate, oinstructor, :NEW.evaluation);   
  END IF;
END;
```

This compiles, however when i test this by trying to update an existing attendance.evaluation i get the following error:

```
Error report:
SQL Error: ORA-04091: table.ATTENDANCE is mutating, trigger/function may not see it
ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger 'OPS$1022005.AUDIT_ATT_EVAL'
04091. 00000 -  "table %s.%s is mutating, trigger/function may not see it"
*Cause:    A trigger (or a user defined plsql function that is referenced in
           this statement) attempted to look at (or modify) a table that was
           in the middle of being modified by the statement which fired it.
*Action:   Rewrite the trigger (or function) so it does not read that table.
```

As always i would appreciate any help to steer me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mutating error normally occurs when we are performing some DML operations(INSERT/UPDATE in your case) and we are trying to select the affected record from the same trigger(you are fetching from attendence table). So basically we are trying to select records in the trigger from the table that owns the trigger. This creates inconsistency and Oracle throws a mutating error

```
create or replace 
trigger audit_att_eval
   AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE OF evaluation ON attendance
   FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
  --fname VARCHAR2(22);
  --sname VARCHAR2(22);
  --ctitle VARCHAR(30);
  --ostartdate DATE;
  --oinstructor VARCHAR2(12);

CURSOR fetch_audit_details
   IS 
    SELECT student.first_name, student.surname, course.title, offering.start_date, offering.instructor
  --INTO fname, sname, ctitle, ostartdate, oinstructor
  FROM student
      , course
      , offering
   -- ,attendence   i have removed this because this is not allowed in this trigger
  WHERE student.student_id = :NEW.student_id    --use the new student id
  AND :NEW.offering_id = offering.offering_id   ----use the new offering_id
  AND offering.course_id = course.course_id;     

fetch_audit_row fetch_audit_details%ROWTYPE;

BEGIN

IF (:NEW.evaluation = 0)
  THEN
  --You need details only when evaluation value is 0 ,thats why i put this inside 
  --condition
   OPEN fetch_audit_details;
   FETCH fetch_audit_details INTO fetch_audit_row;
   CLOSE fetch_audit_details;

  --check whether this cursor returns null ,do what you need to do in this situation??

 INSERT INTO eval_audit
     VALUES (fetch_audit_row.first_name, fetch_audit_row.surname, fetch_audit_row.title, fetch_audit_row.start_date, fetch_audit_row.instructor, 0);   
   END IF;
  END;
```